# How to go back with refreshed data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to go back with back button or with arrow button in flutter but, when i go back to the previous page the data is not refreshed.

I am going to the next page (from page1 to page2) when i click the button from this code

```
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                retturn Page2();
          }));
```

And made some changes on the Page2() that will effect the Page1(), then from the arrow button on the appbar or the back button in the android we have two options to go back if we  press any one of these to go to the Page1() from page2() then the i want to refresed data from firebase

Comment: What data are you talking about?
Please be more specific.

Comment: Is the back button in the AppBar? Is the page you are trying to get back to on the Navigation stack? Can you post more code so this question makes more sense?

Comment: I have made some changes in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `await Navigator.push` and then call `setState` 
`Navigator.pop` can also pass data back

code snippet

```
result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SelectionScreen()),
    );

setState(() {});
...
Navigator.pop(context, 'Yep!');
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Returning Data',
    home: HomeScreen(),
  ));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String result = "wait Navigator.pop";

  _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SelectionScreen()),
    );

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Returning Data Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(result),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
              },
              child: Text('Pick an option, any option!'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pick an option'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the screen and return "Yep!" as the result.
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'Yep!');
                },
                child: Text('Yep!'),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the screen and return "Nope!" as the result.
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'Nope.');
                },
                child: Text('Nope.'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It will refresh the page with new data

Comment: Yes. it will refresh page with new data. because after await push, you then call setState

Comment: I have updated example gif and full code to make it more clear